# Geospatial Open Data from Sri Lanka or India

Tags: geospatial, india

Has anyone come across open geospatial data sets from India or Sri Lanka?

I'm looking for city, district and state/province boundaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to look for it at GeoCommons.com?

- [India states](http://geocommons.com/maps/263217/details)
- [India state boundaries](http://geocommons.com/maps/160870/details)
- [India states](http://geocommons.com/overlays/330108)

Answer (score 3):

Also check out GADM:
http://www.gadm.org/
This database is worldwide and has different administrative levels available, including for India (4 different levels).