# Open GIS data for SE Asia - Political and Administrative Polygons

Tags: geospatial, government, asia

I am looking for city and neighboorhood level (and other administrative divisions) data for as many countries in SE Asia as possible. It must be free to access and use. Trusted/official data is preferred (i.e. local, municipal, national governments, universities).
Specific countries and the administrative levels include:

Cambodia: (Section (ខណ្ឌ khan), Quarter (សង្កាត់ sangkat), Commune(ឃុំ khum), Municipality (ក្រុង krong), Village (ភូមិ phum).

Indonesia: City (Kota), Distrik (district), Desa (villages, Kelurahan (urban communities), Rukun Tetangga (neighborhoods) and Rukun Warga (???).

Malaysia: District (Malay: Daerah; Jajahan in Kelantan and Bahagian in Sabah and Sarawak), Muhkim.

Taiwan: Neighborhoods within villages, towns and cities.

Vietnam: Ward, (Phường), District-level town/Town (Thị xã), Ward (Phường) Commune (Xã), Commune-level town/Township (Thị trấn)

I have grabbed what I can from Open Street Map, Geonames, and http://www.diva-gis.org/ but I'm looking for what is listed above. 
I have taken suggestions Stack Exchange questions (http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/) I have also looked at https://opendatainception.io/ (**awesome** website, check it out).

I am looking for vector data only (polygons, points, lines). Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: seems like to get multi-country, you'll have a compromise on full coverage (e.g. OSM)

Comment: If you want help filling in the gaps, please update your question with a list of what data you still need.

Comment: You'll probably need to go country-by-country finding local sources. Eg, this question has some resources for India: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/geospatial-open-data-from-sri-lanka-or-india

Comment: I am certainly going country by country, I will update my question to be more specific shortly. Apologies for being vague.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any link to here :

- http://www.diva-gis.org/
- https://hub.arcgis.com/pages/open-data
- https://gadm.org/
- http://dataportals.org/

If you are a ESRI ArcGIS Desktop user then they have ArcGIS Online that has these polygons that you can download:

- http://www.arcgis.com/home/index.html

Finally, if you live in those areas or not, you may need to contact their GIS university department that they may help you out for more information.